# Can I omit the word 'about'?

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence, can I omit the word 'about'? If not, I'd like to know the difference between 'tell somebody something' and 'tell somebody about something'.

> I found the tea culture in Japan you told me about very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

When you use "tell somebody *something*" you are expressing [indirect speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_speech) and the *something* should normally be a complete sentence. For example,

> I told you I would be on time.

> I told you tea culture is important in Japan.

When you tell somebody *about* <something>, the <something> can be just a noun phrase, as in your example.

Comment: Also, you tell someone a fact, but when you tell them _about_ something, you give them a longer description which may include numerous facts.